# How to use dynode to connect to local dynamo db

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have installed dynamo DB on my local machine if I run

```
sudo systemctl status dynamodb.service
```

I am getting this out put

```
Aug 01 16:36:22 evbooth-Latitude-E6430 systemd[1]: Started DynamoDB on Localhost.
Aug 01 16:36:24 evbooth-Latitude-E6430 java[4444]: Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Aug 01 16:36:24 evbooth-Latitude-E6430 java[4444]: Port:        8000
Aug 01 16:36:24 evbooth-Latitude-E6430 java[4444]: InMemory:        false
Aug 01 16:36:24 evbooth-Latitude-E6430 java[4444]: DbPath:        /opt/dynamodb/data
Aug 01 16:36:24 evbooth-Latitude-E6430 java[4444]: SharedDb:        true
Aug 01 16:36:24 evbooth-Latitude-E6430 java[4444]: shouldDelayTransientStatuses:        false
Aug 01 16:36:24 evbooth-Latitude-E6430 java[4444]: CorsParams:        *
```

In one of my application, I am using dynode to connect to dynamo db remote I just want to know how can I use the dynode to connect to my local dynamo db.

Comment: Just change the config to connect to localhost:8000 ?

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge But dynode auth is this `dynode.auth({accessKeyId: "AWSAccessKey", secretAccessKey: "SecretAccessKey"});`